# Show Rokbox popup using jQuery or Mootools

Tags: javascript, jquery, mootools

I have this HTML:

```
a id="rt-popupmodule-button" data-rokbox data-rokbox-element="#rt-popupmodule" href="#" class="hidden">rt-popupmodule /a
```

It opens Rokbox popup window and I need to open it either jQuery or Mootools or pure JS.

I make jQuery Ajax call and I need to open this popup after Ajax request done, here is the code:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'post',
    data: {
        form: contactForm.serializeArray()
    },
    dataType: 'html',
    async: true,
    success: function(response){        
        jQuery(document).find('#rt-popupmodule-button').trigger('click');       
    } 
});
```

But nothing happens unfortunately.
Is it possible to fire an event to open this Rokbox popup?

Comment: Try `document.getElementById('rt-popupmodule-button').click();`

Comment: Genius! Thanks )) It works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

You can use plain JavaScript on this one.

```
document.getElementById('rt-popupmodule-button').click();
```

That will select the element by its ID, and then trigger a click on it.